# Why isn't Cloud Endpoints for Golang in GAE Standard Environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine-go

Hey does anyone know why [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/endpoints/) for Go-lang isn't in the standard environment on Google App Engine? It's only seemed to be officially supported/documented for Python / Java.

Is it because

A) Cloud Endpoints is coming to Golang soon / someday.

B) Cloud Endpoints isn't so great, so it's not going to be implemented in Golang.

C) Something else.

There's this "non-standard" lib https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/go-endpoints but it hasn't been updated in 9 months.

I'm trying to choose between Python and Golang for a GAE project, and this lack of support for Cloud Endpoints is giving me pause.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Product manager Dan Ciruli [answered this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/ojw2i6dqCpg) on the google-appengine-go mailing list :

> There are two primary reasons, and the second is a byproduct of the
>   first. We've had much less uptake on the Endpoints Go framework --
>   perhaps because, in the words of a developer I spoke to, "Go just
>   isn't a 'framework' language." Unlike, Java, Python (and, say, Node),
>   most developers using Go don't use a framework for writing an API
>   backend.
>
> And, at least partially because of that, we aren't staffed on the
>   Endpoints team to build and support a framework in Go.

He added:

> All hope is not lost. You can put a Go API behind Endpoints today on
>   GAE Flex or Container Engine (without framework) using the Extensible
>   Server Proxy. And later this year, we should be able to get the ESP
>   deployed in GAE standard environment, you'll get the full power there,
>   too.

Comment: Extensible Server Proxy (see e.g. https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/running-esp-localdev)

Comment: Hey Dan. Any status update with golang, standard app engine and cloud endpoints?   I sincerely hope so.